# Unable to connect postfix to amavisd in FreeBSD-11 jail

Tags: postfix, freebsd, amavis, freebsd-ports

Attempting to send a message through `Postfix` on a jailed instance of `FreeBSD-11` results in the following error when `amavisd` is configured:

```
/usr/local/sbin/amavisd[47180]: (!)DENIED ACCESS from IP 127.0.32.1, policy bank ''
```

The lo interface for the jail is cloned to `127.0.32.1`.  The only place where this address is explicitly used in any of the related configuration files is in `postfix/main.cf` for the inet_interfaces assignment (`postfix` listening address assignments cannot be redirected by the jail software). All other places, including `/etc/hosts`, refer solely to `127.0.0.1`.

Does anyone have this combination (`postfix`/`amavisd`) running successfully in a `FreeBSD jail`?  How is it done?

If not then what alternatives are there to obtain the same benefits provided by `amavisd` if this combination cannot be made to work in a `FreeBSD jail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running *Postfix (3.3.0)* inside a jailed *FreeBSD* instance be aware that the automatic `localhost/127.0.0.1` remapping to that jail's assigned cloned `lo#` interface does not work for the network interfaces defined in Postfix's `.../etc/postfix/main.cf`.  The actual IP address assigned to the cloned `lo#` i/f must be specified.   Because of this `.../etc/amavisd.conf` also must be modified to allow connections from that cloned i/f address in place of the default, `127.0.0.1`.

For example:

If `/etc/rc.conf` on the host system contains:

```
cloned_interfaces="lo1"
ipv4_addrs_lo1="127.0.31.1/32"
ipv6_addrs_lo1="::31"
```

And a jail using `lo1:127.0.31.1` as its loopback i/f address is used to run *Postfix* together with *Amavisd* then the following configuration is required in the jail:

In `../postfix/main.cf`:

```
inet_interfaces = 127.0.31.1, 192.168.31.31, A.B.C.31, . . .
```

And in `../etc/amavisd.conf`:

```
@inet_acl = qw( 127.0.31.1 [::31]);
```

And for completeness:

If *saslauthd* is installed and `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes` and `smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd` are set in `../etc/postfix/main.cf` then the file `/usr/local/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf` must be created and configured to contain:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```